# Why is coherence time the integral over (negative) infinite delay time?

Tags: electric-fields, double-slit-experiment

Let $\vec{E_{1}}$ be a wave of the some profile.

To observe the interference between these two waves, of the same profile, at different times, $t$ and $t + \tau$, the autocorrelation function

$ \xi(t) = \frac{\overline{\vec{E_{1}}(t)} \vec{E_{1}}(t+\tau)}{\overline{\vec{E_{1}}(t)} \vec{E_{1}}(t)}$

with the value 1 if the two waves are perfectly correlated.

The coherence time is defined as

$\tau_{c} = \int_{\tau = -\infty}^{\tau = +\infty}|\xi(t)|^{2}.d\tau$

Two questions:

1. clearly the waves are of the same profile so for the interference to occur given a delayed pulse, one wave must move faster than the other. But doesn't this contradicts the fact that the two waves are of the same profile?
2. How should I think about the fact that coherence time is the integral over the negative time delay?